# Install Nginx as reverse proxy before DVWA

Tags: nginx, docker

I want to configure Nginx as a reverse proxy that sits before the web app ( DVWA : Damn vulnerable web Application).

**DVWA runs inside a docker as follows**

```
docker run --expose=8080 -d -p 8080:80 -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_PASS="xxxxxxx" -e VIRTUAL_HOST=192.168.1.52:8080 docker.io/citizenstig/dvwa
```

When I open my browser and go to 192.168.1.52:8080, Everything works fine.

**A separate docker runs as follows**

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

When I open my browser and type 192.168.1.52 it still opens up nginx page instead of my website home page

Comment: Suggest you provide the Nginx configuration and logs. I know Nginx quite well but nothing about Docker, so not providing config/logs you're limiting the people who can answer your question to people who are experienced in both Nginx and Docker.

Answer (score 0):

@[Tim](https://serverfault.com/users/306795/tim) is absolutely right, you need to configure your nginx.

Checking the [docs](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) for the container you are using you:

- need to start nginx *first*
- need to start your other containers after, and with `VIRTUAL_HOST` set:
  `docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.bar.com`

You would then enter the virtual host name in your browsers, and assuming you had appropriate DNS or host entries, or some other way of mapping domain to your nginx-proxy, you would see your app.

Entering your nginx-proxy's IP won't (as far as I can tell) take your traffic through to your app. You need to give nginx a valid `Host:` value for it to route your traffic to the appropriate vhost, and from there, backend.